# C program that is a menu and uses switch case. So far, option A, entering GPA works but for option B, average is wrong

Tags: c

Here is the description of the program that I am trying to make. Option A works but then when I enter Option B afterward, the average is completely wrong.

Description:
    This is a menu driven program in which the user will have to choose what 
    option they want.
    There are options eight options.
    Option A will have the user enter the GPAs.
    Option B will display the average of all GPAs.
    Option C will display the highest GPA.
    Option D will display the lowest GPA.
    Option E will display the adjusted average.
    Option F will see if a certain GPA was entered.
    Option G display the contents of the array.
    Option Q will quit the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    float gpa[1000]; //this is the array for all the GPAs the user enters
    char choice; 
    int i;
    float n;
    float sum = 0;
    float average = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n\nChoose one of the following");
        printf("\nA.Enter GPA");
        printf("\nB.Display Average of all GPA's");
        printf("\nEnter your selection: ");
        scanf_s(" %c", &choice);

        //user enters in GPAs and it gets put into array
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'A':
            printf("\nHow many GPAs are you entering?: ");
            scanf_s("%f", &n);
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                printf("\nEnter GPA: ");
                scanf_s("%f", &gpa[i]);
                if (gpa[i] < 2.0)
                {
                    printf("You need to study harder.");
                }
                if (gpa[i] > 3.5)
                {
                    printf("Nice work.");
                }
            }
        }

        //GPAs from the array are added up and divided by n, how many GPAs 
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'B':
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                sum += gpa[i];
            }

            average = sum / n;
            printf("The average is: %.2f", average);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your first `for` loop, why are you looping for `1..n` and in the second `for` loop for `0..n` ?  Generally for *N* iterations, programs loop from 0 -> *N*-1.  You are not entering anything into `gpa[0]`, yet you sum it into option `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is not putting a GPA into `gpa[0]`.

This is because the first `for()` loop is looping from 1 to <= `N`.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    ...
    scanf_s("%f", &gpa[i]);
```

This should probably be 0 -> `N-1`.  It's leaving `gpa[0]` with some random (undefined) value.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

The bug is because, when calculating the average, you compute from the `0th` element:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

If the loop constructs were both the same, it would probably be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the syntax of "switch-case" in C:

```
  switch (choice)
  {
    case 'A': {
      // some work for A choice..
      break;
    }
    case 'B': {
      // some work for B choice..
      break;
    }
    default:
      // print "Error in input" or something
      break;
  }
```

Let's mark some points:

1. There is only 1 switch on 'choice' variable.
2. Every end of case MUST end with "break;" unless, you will fall down to the next case.
3. You don't have to use "{ }" for the cases but I recomend from visual reasons.
4. I also recommend to use "default" at the end in order to handle all cases. You will land on default if 'choice' will be not 'A' and not 'B'

I also think that your 'n' variable should be int because it's a whole number.
and I already see someone spot your bug, so good luck :)

Comment: This is a good point @Elad Aharon has made - the program has multiple `switch()` statements, whereas there should be only one.